# Cutting a string into array of <"x" chars each

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a situation where my string can't go past a certain point, so what I want to do is cut it into smaller strings of "x" characters, and then print them one by one on top of each other. They don't all need to be equal, if x is 5, and I have an 11 character string, printing 3 lines with 5, 5, and 1 characters is fine. Is there an easy way to do this in C#?

Example:

```
string Test = "This is a test string";
stringarray = Cutup(Test, 5); 
//Result:
//"This "
//"is a "
//"test "
//"strin"
//"g"
```

Comment: Did you even try to solve this for yourself?

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
    public string[] Cutcup(string s, int l)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i += l)
        {
            result.Add(s.Substring(i, Math.Min(5, s.Substring(i).Length)));
        }

        return result.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: You'll get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException if the last string of the iteration is not atleast 5 characters.

Comment: `i <= s.Length - l` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could cut up the strings then do a test.lastIndexOf(' '); If that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use the String Manipultion function **Substring()** and a for loop to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example

```
int maxChars = 5;
            String myStr = "This is some text used in testing this method of splitting a string and just a few more chars and the string is complete";
            List<String> mySubStrings = new List<String>();
            while (myStr.Length > maxChars)
            {
                mySubStrings.Add(myStr.Substring(0,maxChars));
                myStr = myStr.Substring(maxChars);
            }
            mySubStrings.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        string testString = "This is a test string";
        string chunkBuilder = "";
        int chunkSize = 5;
        for (int i = 0; i <= testString.Length-1; i++)
        {
            chunkBuilder += testString[i];

            if (chunkBuilder.Length == chunkSize || i == testString.Length - 1)
            {
                result.Add(chunkBuilder);
                chunkBuilder = "";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another try, with less string concatenations

```
string Test = "This is a test string";
List<string> parts = new List<string>();
int i = 0; 
do
{
   parts.Add(Test.Substring(i,System.Math.Min(5, Test.Substring(i).Length))); 
   i+= 5;
} while (i < Test.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple more ways.  `Cutup2` below is more efficient but less pretty.  Both pass the test case given.

```
private static IEnumerable<string> Cutup(string given, int chunkSize)
{
    var skip = 0;
    var iterations = 0;
    while (iterations * chunkSize < given.Length)
    {
        iterations++;                
        yield return new string(given.Skip(skip).Take(chunkSize).ToArray());
        skip += chunkSize;
    }
}

private static unsafe IEnumerable<string> Cutup2(string given, int chunkSize)
{
    var pieces = new List<string>();
    var consumed = 0;

    while (consumed < given.Length)
    {
        fixed (char* g = given)
        {
            var toTake = consumed + chunkSize > given.Length 
                         ? given.Length - consumed 
                         : chunkSize;

            pieces.Add(new string(g, consumed, toTake));
        }

        consumed += chunkSize;
    }

    return pieces;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I once made an extensionmethod that can be used for this:

```
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Subsequencise<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, int subsequenceLength)
    {
        var enumerator = input.GetEnumerator();
        SubsequenciseParameter parameter = new SubsequenciseParameter { Next = enumerator.MoveNext() };
        while (parameter.Next)
            yield return getSubSequence(enumerator, subsequenceLength, parameter);

    }


    private static IEnumerable<T> getSubSequence<T>(IEnumerator<T> enumerator, int subsequenceLength, SubsequenciseParameter parameter)
    {
        do
        {
            yield return enumerator.Current;
        } while ((parameter.Next = enumerator.MoveNext()) && --subsequenceLength > 0);
    } 

    // Needed to let the Subsequencisemethod know when to stop, since you cant use out or ref parameters in an yield-return method.
    class SubsequenciseParameter
    {
        public bool Next { get; set; }
    }
```

then you can do this:

```
string Test = "This is a test string";
stringarray = Test.Subsequencise(5).Select(subsequence => new String(subsequence.Toarray())).Toarray();
```

Answer (score 0):

All in one line

```
        var size = 5;

        var results = Enumerable.Range(0, (int)Math.Ceiling(test.Length / (double)size))
                                .Select(i => test.Substring(i * size, Math.Min(size, test.Length - i * size)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rather LINQy one-liner:

```
static IEnumerable<string> SliceAndDice1( string s , int n )
{
  if ( s == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException("s");
  if ( n < 1 ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("n");

  int i = 0 ;
  return s.GroupBy( c => i++ / n ).Select( g => g.Aggregate(new StringBuilder() , (sb,c)=>sb.Append(c)).ToString() ) ;
}
```

If that gives you a headache, try the more straightforward

```
static IEnumerable<string> SliceAndDice2( string s , int n )
{
  if ( s == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException("s") ;
  if ( n < 1 ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("n") ;

  int i = 0 ;
  for ( i = 0 ; i < s.Length-n ; i+=n )
  {
    yield return s.Substring(i,n) ;
  }
  yield return s.Substring(i) ;

}
```